# Google Compute Engine as a Minecraft server

Tags: port-forwarding, minecraft, google-compute-engine

I'm working on using a Google Compute Engine instance running CentOS 6.6 as a Minecraft server, and I'm curious if it is technically possible to use port forwarding to allow other users to access it. I've been working with it for a couple hours now, and I've created a Firewall rule opening tcp:25565 (the relevant port). When my friend tries to connect, I'm seeing his IP in the game console as part of a "connection lost" error message. The server has a static IP which he is using to try to connect. I am fully able to connect to the instance via SSH from my personal computer, which is how I've been interacting with it the entire time.

Java is updated to 1.8 on the instance, and the server is running smoothly, it's just a question of allowing other people to access it. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Why not spin up a complete VPS like in, say, DigitalOcean? less hassle IMO. I still find GCE interesting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright after a little more research I ended up finding out how to do this myself. The easiest thing to do is [follow through this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server) that will explain how to do it. Don't skip anything! That's how I ended up getting stuck for a while - I didn't read close enough.

In my case, I wanted to set up a Tekkit server, and that's easy enough to do as well. All you have to to is download the server file for the modpack that you'd like in place of the Minecraft server file. Do this either using `wget` in the Google Compute console or `scp` to copy it from one machine to another via ssh. (Both worked for me.) You can ignore the part about editing "eula.txt" if the file does not appear, since that was only a recent implementation in Minecraft 1.7 or 1.8 (not sure which).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to port forward.

1. Have an External IP that's static.
2. Make sure your ports for the server are open on the internal localhost.
3. Make sure your ports for the server are open on the gcloud firewall

VPC Network> Firewall Rules